# Как грамотно вывести массив Php

Tags: php, массивы

Изначально имею такой массив:

```
Array ( 

[0] => WP_Post Object ([ID] => 48 [content] => Товар1  [namecat] => Категория 1 ) 

[1] => WP_Post Object ([ID] => 49 [content] => Товар1  [namecat] => Категория 2 )

[2] => WP_Post Object ([ID] => 50 [content] => Товар2  [namecat] => Категория 1 ) 

[3] => WP_Post Object ([ID] => 51 [content] => Товар2  [namecat] => Категория 2 )

)
```

В конечном итоге мне нужно вывести список категорий и товаров вида:

```
*Категория 1

  -> Товар1

  -> Товар2

*Категория 2

  -> Товар1

  -> Товар2
```

Как грамотно перебрать массив чтобы получить необходимый вывод?

Answer (score 1):

```
$newArr = [];
//Создаём массив нужного вида из имеющегося:
foreach ($array as $element){
    $newArr[$element->namecat][] = $element->content;
}

//Выводим массим
foreach ($newArr as $name => $cat) {
    echo '*' . $name . '<br>';
    foreach($cat as $goods) {
        echo '-> ' . $goods . '<br>';
    }
}
```